# Question related to textbox used to keyin password

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a c# winform application. The application will minimize to the system tray, and there are two options for the user to choose from, show and exit . Both are working well. Right now i need to implement a function whereby when the user chooses exit, I need to display a textbox for the user to key in his/her password just above the system tray. The inputbox must mask the character type by the user as the user will be typing his/her password. I want to know whether there are any other way other than creating a new form with a textbox to fulfill this feature.

I tried to import use the visual basic textbox to perform this but unfortunately, I cannot mask the characters typed by the user. Are there any other way to do so other than creating a new form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Textbox.UseSystemPasswordChar` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.usesystempasswordchar.aspx).

Comment: I have used that before in one of my other form. Right now i am wondering whether can i just put an inputbox like those avaliable in visual basic for my user to key in his/her password without a need to create a new form to contain an inputbox.

Comment: @abd: There is no built-in function to do this.  You need to make a form.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that i will go ahead to create a form to contain an inputbox for the user to key in his/her password.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's no out-of-the-box solution for what you're trying to do, but the .NET Framework makes available to you all the components to easily make it happen.

- The bad news: you need to create a new form that contains the input fields you want to display to users.
- The good news: you can use a standard [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx), and set it so it will hide the password characters.

There are two parts to showing a password [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx):

1. [Set the `TextBox` to hide password characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.usesystempasswordchar.aspx)
2. [Choose the character to display for passwords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx)